# Node.js network performance suffers drastically under load testing on AWS

Tags: node.js, networking, amazon-web-services

I have the following Node.js code written as a very basic HTTP server. It's purpose is to ingest large numbers of requests containing base64 data, and write that data to S3 as an image. The S3-writing aspect is working fantastically and has no issues. However, the initial request seems to take an abnormally long time under load.

**server.js**

```
http.createServer(function(req, res){
    if (url.parse(req.url).pathname == '/processimage' && req.method.toLowerCase() == 'post') {
        var startTime = new Date();
        var rawBody = '';
        req.on('data', function(chunk) { 
            rawBody += chunk;
        });

        req.on('end', function() {
            console.log('REQUEST FINISHED: ' + (new Date() - startTime) + ' ms');
            // Process image, upload to S3
            res.writeHead(200);
            res.end('data');
        }
        return;
    } else {
        // Other requests
    }
}).listen(1347);
```

I am also timing the image processing section, but it is performing fine and not relevant to this question.

To test this, I have written a script that POSTs test data containing the base64 of approximately 500k characters (2-3mb original images). When testing this locally, everything works fine. My output is:

```
REQUEST FINISHED: 9ms
REQUEST FINISHED: 23ms
REQUEST FINISHED: 18ms
```

etc.

However, after deploying the code to AWS on an x-large instance, I see the following:

```
REQUEST FINISHED: 499ms
REQUEST FINISHED: 2493ms
REQUEST FINISHED: 1784ms
REQUEST FINISHED: 3440ms
REQUEST FINISHED: 994ms
REQUEST FINISHED: 36043ms
```

Essentially, when stress testing this, approximately 1 in every 30 requests seems to take 10+ seconds (even 30+ seconds in some cases) just to go through the request pipeline. As you can see in my code, there is zero processing being done on the data before the times are calculated, so this means that somewhere between "req.on('data')" and "req.on('end')", there is a massive delay.

My question is: is there some kind of processing happening between req.on('data') and req.on('end') that would cause this POST to take so long? Is it possible that the host machine is choking on these requests for some reason (Ubuntu 12.04, x-large instance, 14GB memory, 4x CPUs)?

Comment: If you are running lots of requests at the same time, then you're probably just seeing the single node.js thread serving multiple requests at once and thus the total throughput time for any single request gets stretched out as it switches between each request whenever there's an async operation.  You don't show what the node.js server is actually doing with the data it receives and that is probably pretty pertinent to the issue as that's probably where a bunch of the CPU goes.

Comment: Also keep in mind that the data doesn't arrive all at once.  It arrives in chunks and each chunk triggers a `req.on('data')` callback.  It will likely take many of these callbacks to serve 500k chunks of data.  If you throw lots of requests at the server at once, your code will have multiple requests "in-flight" at the same time (each with their own request object) and you'll get a chunk from request A, then a chunk from request B and so on.  It won't just do all of request A first and then do request B.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks - I've actually removed all of the processing code in order to narrow down the issue. The complete code looks like:

req.on('end', function() {
   // console.log...
   res.writeHead(200);
   res.end('success');
}

You are correct that the chunks take some time to come in, and some network latency would be expected. However it seems odd that when using the same base64 code for repeated requests, the timing ranges from 300ms (acceptable) to 36000 (not at all).

Comment: There may be a memory bottleneck concatenating the base64 chunks. Try `push`ing the chunks into an array in `req.on('data',...` and `.join()` them in `req.on('end',...`. By simply concatenating strings, you're asking the garbage collector to collect the previous string. Under high load, this is either cutting into time better spent handling the requests or node is hitting it's 1.5gb memory limit

Answer (score 0):

This is likely going to take some extensive logging to see what is happening.  You have multiple requests, each with large data which will be processed in multiple chunks.  I'd say that the first thing to do is to log exactly when each chunk from each request is processed and then you can get an idea what order things are happening in and see where that leads.  Here's a first pass idea at logging that:

```
// helper function
logDelta(id, start, msg) {
    var delta = new Date() - start;
    console.log(id + ": (" + delta + ") - " + msg);
}

var reqCntr = 0;
http.createServer(function(req, res){
    if (url.parse(req.url).pathname == '/processimage' && req.method.toLowerCase() == 'post') {
        // place an id on the request for logging purposes
        req.trackerID = reqCntr++;
        console.log(req.trackerID + ": Begin Request");

        var startTime = new Date();
        var rawBody = '';
        var chunkCntr = 0;
        req.on('data', function(chunk) { 
            logDelta(req.trackerID, startTime, "chunk(" + chunkCntr + "), length = " + chunk.length);
            ++chunkCntr;
            rawBody += chunk;
        });

        req.on('end', function() {
            logDelta(req.trackerID, startTime, "Request Finished");
            // Process image, upload to S3
            res.writeHead(200);
            res.end('data');
        }
        return;
    } else {
        // Other requests
    }
}).listen(1347);
```

Then, you may have to do some processing of the log data in order to be able to follow the timing of each event in each individual request, particularly the long running ones.  This will likely then offer you a clue about where to look next.

---

FYI, there are a bunch of different places in the stack where you could be hitting a bottleneck.  If, for example, you're firing data at the server faster than it can be processed (either at the OS level or at the node level), then the TCP buffers will fill up at some point and incoming packets will be dropped or the socket will be placed into some sort of flow control.

If you're running on a shared server, you may not have access to the whole TCP buffer either.

---

Here's a scheme that would collect all the history for each connection and then output it to the log at once (making dissection of a single connection easier, but obscuring the sequence of events among different connections).

```
var reqCntr = 0;
http.createServer(function(req, res){
    var log = [];
    var id;
    var startTime = new Date();

    // helper function
    logDelta(msg) {
        var delta = new Date() - startTime;
        log.push(id + ": (" + delta + ") - " + msg);
    }

    if (url.parse(req.url).pathname == '/processimage' && req.method.toLowerCase() == 'post') {
        // place an id on the request for logging purposes
        id = reqCntr++;
        log.push(id + ": Begin Request");

        var rawBody = '';
        var chunkCntr = 0;
        req.on('data', function(chunk) { 
            logDelta("chunk(" + chunkCntr + "), length = " + chunk.length);
            ++chunkCntr;
            rawBody += chunk;
        });

        req.on('end', function() {
            // dump connection history to console.log()
            logDelta("Request Finished");
            console.log(log.join("/n"));
            // Process image, upload to S3
            res.writeHead(200);
            res.end('data');
        }
        return;
    } else {
        // Other requests
    }
}).listen(1347);
```

Comment: This is super helpful - I added this to my code and am able to see response times. It still works fine until load testing, during which some requests will take 20+ seconds, but now it actually shows individual chunks: Chunk 1: 3ms, Chunk 2: 1000ms, etc. So somewhere in receiving that second chunk, a lot of time passed.

Comment: @MattFuller - There are a number of Unix utilities you can run on to examine what's going on at the TCP level where you can see statistics about flow control, drop packets, retransmissions, etc...  I don't remember them off-hand, but you can probably find with Google.  You may want to see next if there are issues at the TCP level.  You may need larger TCP buffering or some other TCP tweaks if packets are arriving faster than they can be processed.